# Date of last changed dsrm admin password

Tags: powershell

Does it exist a way to get the last changed date DSRM admin password in PowerShell (or maybe using ntdsutil) ?

The only thing I found it how to reset but they don't say when.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322672

Comment: Easiest way to keep track is by [sync'ing it from a domain account](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/03/11/ds-restore-mode-password-maintenance/), then inspect the `pwdLastSet` attribute for the domain user

Comment: Thanks for this advice !